# Is it possible to use chrome dev tool on my microsoft edge?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, microsoft-edge

I just want to inspect the elements [image]on chrome dev tool. Any way to connect them? Like the image given

Comment: What's stopping you from using Microsoft Edge's own F12 developer tools?

Comment: I'm much familiar with chrome dev tools. :( @BoltClock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The closest attempt appears to be this project: [IEDiagnosticsAdapter](https://github.com/Microsoft/IEDiagnosticsAdapter). However, it doesn't appear to be actively maintained and I could only get it to work with IE11 (not Edge). It isn't full featured either.

I don't think Edge has builtin support for the [Chrome DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Edge supports DevTools protocol partially.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-protocol/